# CSS Table First Column Background

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to use CSS to change the background of my table cells.
If the first cell in a row is hovered over, I want ONLY that cell to have  a red background.
If any other cells in the row are hovered over, I want all cells in the row to hioghlight green EXCEPT the first cell.

Is that possible with just CSS?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, please take a time to go through the welcome tour to know your way around here , read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Try using `td:nth-of-type(1):hover{}` for the first cell and `tr:hover td:not(:nth-of-type(1)){ }` For the other cells. The problem here that the second part is also acting when hovering the first cell

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to achieve something similar by styling the row hover, then resetting the style with adjacent selectors:

```css
tr:hover td {
  background: green;
}
tr:hover td:first-child,
tr td:first-child:hover ~ td {
  background: transparent;
}
tr td:first-child:hover {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks delinear.
Works a treat.

Comment: awesome answer.